# Word completion in a file using nvim-cmp

Tags: autocomplete, neovim

I am using `nvim-com` to autocomplete in neovim.

When working with a `lua` file I have found that I get suggestions for completion of normal English words present in the file, as showing in the following image (they are also labelled by 'Text' in the suggestions generated).

[image: Text Completion Prompt]

Bur when working with a `tex` file I am not seeing any such suggestions.
For instance, the word 'probability' may be appearing many times in my file but when writing 'prob' I don't get any suggestions (Though if I press `<c-x><c-n>` it does complete to probability automatically).

Can I change the configuration for `nvim-cmp` to get suggestions for normal text? This would save a lot of time.

Following is my set up for `nvim-cmp.`

```
local cmp = require 'cmp'
local luasnip = require 'luasnip'
require('luasnip.loaders.from_vscode').lazy_load()
luasnip.config.setup {}

cmp.setup {
  snippet = {
    expand = function(args)
      luasnip.lsp_expand(args.body)
    end,
  },
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert {
    ['<C-n>'] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(),
    ['<C-p>'] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(),
    ['<C-d>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
    ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
    ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete {},
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm {
      behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Replace,
      select = true,
    },
    ['<Tab>'] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
      if cmp.visible() then
        cmp.select_next_item()
      elseif luasnip.expand_or_locally_jumpable() then
        luasnip.expand_or_jump()
      else
        fallback()
      end
    end, { 'i', 's' }),
    ['<S-Tab>'] = cmp.mapping(function(fallback)
      if cmp.visible() then
        cmp.select_prev_item()
      elseif luasnip.locally_jumpable(-1) then
        luasnip.jump(-1)
      else
        fallback()
      end
    end, { 'i', 's' }),
  },
  sources = {
    { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
    --{ name = 'luasnip' },
    {
      name = 'buffer',
      opts = {
        get_bufnrs = function()
          return vim.api.nvim_list_bufs()
        end
      },
    },
    { name = 'path' },
  },
}
```